# Hilbert's inequality for $\left|\sum_{n,m}a_n \bar a_m\right|$.

Tags: sequences-and-series, inequality, complex-numbers

We know that, an Hilbert's inequality states
$$\left|\sum_{n\neq m}\frac{a_n \bar{a}_m}{n-m}\right|\leq\pi \sum_n |a_n|^2$$
Give $a_n, b_n$ two sequences of complex numbers. Then write an inequality of Hilbert-type for
$$\left|\sum_{n,m}a_n \bar b_m\right|$$
Any suggestions please?

Comment: It should be $$\left|\sum_{n\neq m}\frac{u_{n}\overline{u}_{m}}{n-m}\right|.$$

Comment: How are the $a_n$'s, $b_m$'s and $u_k$'s related?

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis, I've edited my post. Thank you for you remark.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For general complex sequences $a_{n},b_{m}
 $, $1\leq n,m\leq R
 $, we have $$\left|\sum_{n,m}a_{n}\overline{b}_{m}\right|=\left|\sum_{n}a_{n}\sum_{m}\overline{b}_{n}\right|\leq\sum_{n}\left|a_{n}\right|\sum_{m}\left|b_{m}\right|\leq\max\left\{ \left(\sum_{n}\left|a_{n}\right|\right)^{2},\left(\sum_{m}\left|b_{m}\right|\right)^{2}\right\} \leq R\max\left\{ \sum_{n}\left|a_{n}\right|^{2},\sum_{m}\left|b_{m}\right|^{2}\right\} 
 $$ by Cauchy-Schwarz. We can get a “more similar” Hilbert inequality with some hypothesys. In fact it is possible to show that if $\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left|a_{n}\right|^{2}<\infty
 $ and $\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\left|b_{m}\right|^{2}<\infty
 $ and if we put $$c_{r}=\begin{cases}
1/r, & r\neq0\\
0, & r=0
\end{cases}
 $$ then $$\left|\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}c_{n-m}a_{n}b_{m}\right|\leq\pi^{2}\sum_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}\left|a_{n}\right|^{2}\sum_{m\in\mathbb{Z}}\left|b_{m}\right|^{2}.
 $$

Comment: Tank you very much. Maybe the $\pi^2$ is $\pi$ in the latest inequality.

Comment: @Mark I've found a paper with $\pi^{2}$, I don't know if it's possible to take $\pi$ in this case.